# boostrap override checkbox label css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a simple checkbox label override. However I don't seem to have the selector correct:

default in bootstrap forms.less

```
.checkbox label, .radio label {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

my addition in base.less

```
.checkbox {
    .label {
        color: @grey;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work (if I can change the radio label at the same time too, that's fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing a class "label" and not the label itself:

```
.checkbox, .radio {
    label {
        color: @grey;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, got it now